# using tabcapture chrome extansion api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screen-capture, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to record the user screen to create a gif,
trying to use the chrome API **captureTab** without success,
I tried to start the API from the content script got undefined then from an iframe with my extension code and got the exception
**Unchecked runtime.lastError: Error starting tab capture**
I am using **manifest version 3**

from reading the docs the capture API only works in foreground scripts so maybe I didn't understand it,

my manifest

```
{
  "short_name": "***",
  "name": "***",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "screenShotIcon.png",
    "48": "screenShotIcon.png",
    "128": "screenShotIcon.png"
  },

  "key": "***",
  "action": {
    "default_title": "***",
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "screenShotIcon.png",
      "38": "screenShotIcon.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "identity", "scripting", "activeTab"],
  "optional_permissions": ["tabCapture", "downloads"],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "gif.html",
        "gif.js",

      ],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "commands": {
    "_execute_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Q",
        "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+Q"
      }
    },
    "default-action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Q",
        "mac": "Command+Q"
      },
      "description": "default operation "
    }
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["***"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

also the code for starting the iframe

```
iFrame = document.getElementById(popupGifName);
  if (!iFrame) {
    iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    iFrame.id = popupGifName;
    iFrame.style.position = "fixed";
    iFrame.style.height = "100%";
    iFrame.style.width = "100%";
    iFrame.style.border = "none";
    iFrame.style.top = "0px";
    iFrame.style.right = "0px";
    iFrame.style.zIndex = "9000000000000000000";
    document.body.appendChild(iFrame);
  }
  iFrame.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("gif.html");
```

and finally the capture start

```
const getStream = async () => {
    const active = await getActiveTab();

    chrome.tabCapture.capture(
      {
        video: true,
        audio: true,
        videoConstraints: {
          mandatory: {
            minWidth: 16,
            minHeight: 9,
            maxWidth: 854,
            maxHeight: 480,
            maxFrameRate: 60, // Note: Frame rate is variable (0 <= x <= 60).
          },
        },
      },
      (stream) => {
        console.log(stream);
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => getStream()}>start rerecord</button>
      <video
        ref={videoRef}
        width="100px"
        height="100px"
        style={{ position: "absolute" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried everything from running the API from background to the popup and nothing seems to work

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add tabCapture permissions in the manifest file.